# Time zone for Force.com API fiscal date literals?

Tags: api, datetime, salesforce, force.com

I have a question about fiscal date literals in the Force.com API (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm):

For which time zone are date ranges calculated?

For example, suppose we execute the query:

SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE CloseDate = THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER

where, according to our company's fiscal settings, THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER runs from Jan 1 to Mar 31.

Does the range for THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER use...

- the user's time zone? For example, if the user's time zone is GMT-8, THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER = Jan 1 00:00 GMT-8 to Mar 31 23:59 GMT-8 (or Jan 1 08:00 UTC to Mar 31 07:59 UTC)
- the company's default time zone (according to the company profile)? For example, if the company's default time zone is GMT-8, THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER = Jan 1 00:00 GMT-8 to Mar 31 23:59 GMT-8 (or Jan 1 08:00 UTC to Mar 31 07:59 UTC)
- UTC? THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER = Jan 1 00:00 UTC to Mar 31 23:59 UTC
- something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience (fun with reports, not queries) the note from all the way on bottom is valid also for time literals. So it uses running user's timezone setting.

*These values are offset by your timezone. For example, in the Pacific timezone, the earliest valid date is 1699-12-31T16:00:00, or 4:00 PM on December 31, 1699.*

Maybe you can simply create a test record with datetime field just slightly outside the fiscal quarter and query for it "WHERE mydatetimefield__c > THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER"?

See also http://forums.sforce.com/t5/General-Development/SOQL-Date-literal-TODAY-is-evaluated-incorrectly/m-p/43607